# Viewmodel with conditional aggregation (Sums)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have a viewmodel

```
public class RecTotal
{
    public string PayType { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class ReconcileViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RecTotal> RecTotals { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<RecInvoiceLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

How do I create sums of the categories and create a new RecTotal record for each one.  Ex:

```
ReconcileViewModel VM = new ReconcileViewModel();

foreach(POSItemCategory cat in db.POSItemCategories)
            {
                recLineItems.Where(p => p.Category == cat.ID).Sum(p => p.InvPrice);
            }
```

The end result i'm looking for is something like

VM.RecTotal.Add(Sum(TotalPrice), foreach(Category)

I know I'm close but I just cant quite get it.

Comment: cat.ID is a string? the name of category?

Comment: is below solution working for you?

Comment: I eneded up using my list solution.  I was having a problem with your proposed solution and rather than troubleshoot I just used my list solution. Thank you, however, for the advice

Comment: I was having a hard time with your porposed solution figuring out how to make the lambdas work properly for my exact purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, but it is "Ugly" in my opinion and there has to be a better way to do it....

```
var test = new List<RecTotal>();
            foreach (POSItemCategory cat in db.POSItemCategories)
            {
                test.Add(new RecTotal
                {
                    NumberOfItems = recLineItems.Where(p => p.Category == cat.ID).Count(),
                    TotalPrice = recLineItems.Where(p => p.Category == cat.ID).Sum(p => p.InvPrice),
                    PayType = "All",
                    Category = cat.Name,
                    NumberOfInvoices = recLineItems.Where(p => p.Category == cat.ID).Select(p => p.InvID).Distinct().Count()
                });
            };
            VM.RecTotals = test;
```

Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
   var testdata = new List<RecTotal>();

   testdata = recLineItems.Where(x => db.POSItemCategories.Select(a=>a.ID).Contains(x.Category))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                        .Select(
                            x =>
                                new RecTotal()
                                {
                                    Category = x.Key,
                                    PayType = "All",
                                    TotalPrice = x.Sum(z => z.InvPrice),
                                    NumberOfItems = x.Count(),
                                    NumberOfInvoices = x.Select(p => p.InvID).Distinct().Count()
                                }).ToList();
```